403 User is not authorized to perform the desired action
I know this question has already been posted, but the suggested solutions do not work for me.
I have a Firebase Flutter app using Firestore. User can successfully authenticate in Firebase, but when I try to list the contents of a directory or download a file from Storage, I get a 403 error: "User is not authorized to perform the desired action."
Please note that my rules are as open as possible:
rules_version = '2'
service firebase.storage {
match /b/{bucket}/o {
   match /{allPaths=**} {
     allow read, write: if true;
   }
 }
}

Additionally, my app on iOS works fine and is able to download, upload, and list files from Storage. So, the problem must be in the Andorid configuration but I am using the latest google-services.json file, which is the Android equivalent of the GoogleService-Info.plist file that works fine on iOS.
I do not know what else to check or what could possibly be causing the authorization failure.
Any hint?

Please have a look at thread1 and thread2.

i was accessing the default bucket instead of the one i meant to use to store data. The rules on the default bucket did not authorize the access
